# Can wavelets create reproducing Hilbert spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I want to build reproducing Hilbert space applying wavelet transform (instead of orthogonal basis created by Gram-Schmidt process applied on sequence of vectors).
I do not know how to do this and prove it.

in advanced
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: you're talking about reproducing *kernel* hilbert space? if so you can maybe look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space which explains the case of the Fourier transform, indeed a simpler transform but I doubt the conclusion would be very different (but the explicit expression of the Kernel may be complicated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer in the context of Learning Theory but not related to Control Theory. Read the section "4.2 Other Classes of Frame-Based Kernels" from [1] and section "4 Kernel functions based on frames" from [2]. A frame is roughly a redundant basis and those works contruct wavelet frames for a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (that is a Hilbert Space of functions).

[1] [Frames, Reproducing Kernels, Regularization and Learning](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/rakotomamonjy05a/rakotomamonjy05a.pdf).

[2] [On a Class of Support Vector Kernels Based on Frames in function Hilbert Spaces](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/251193/1/WaveletKernel.pdf)